# Constructors with different scopes

Tags: oop, windev

In Windev, is it possible to declare multiple constructors with different scopes? Seems not.

For example:

```
PROCEDURE CONSTRUCTOR (param1, param2)
...

PROCEDURE PROTECTED CONSTRUCTOR (paramx, paramy, paramz)
...
```

When I'm trying to do things this way it gives me an error saying that attributes public, protected and private has to be the same between syntaxes of a same procedure.

Answer (score 0):

> To add a syntax to an existing procedure: In the project explorer,
>   select the procedure. Display the popup menu of the procedure and
>   select "Add a syntax". A new syntax is automatically created in the
>   code editor.

look at this :

https://doc.windev.com/en-US/?1514063&name=surcharge_prototypemultisyntaxe&1514063&name=surcharge_prototypemultisyntaxe

Hope it helps !